# Does field length affect elasticsearch performance?

Tags: elasticsearch

Will the size of the elastic search index decrease (and performance
increase due to reduce memory footprint) if I were to shorten field
names?

Answer (score 0):

Fields names are stored in the field info file, with suffix *.fnm*

FieldName is just a UTF-8 string there.

You could estimate the current size of it and make any assumptions about how much it would save you space, but I’m pretty much sure, that it will be negligible, so there is **very little sense in optimizing field names**.

For example, my tiny playground index of the size 500 Mb with around 100-150 fields have total size of all field info files to be 188 kB which makes it 0.04% out of total size.